# How to add the list to feeder

Tags: scala, gatling

What I want to do is to hit the endpoint with a random list of values. Below is my current solution:

```
import com.gap.loyalty.creditcards.points.domain.PointsRequest
import com.gap.performance.Header._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.core.structure.ScenarioBuilder
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.util.Properties.envOrElse

object PersistList {
    val data: java.util.List[PointList] = Helper.fetchPointsList() //which returns a random list
    val dataList = data.asScala.toList;

    private val postPersist = http("Persist Points")
        .post("/persist")
        .headers(applicationJson)
        .check(status is 200)

    val scenarios: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("Persist Points")
        .feed(dataList).forever(exec(postPersist))
}
```

PointsList

```
String points
Long totalPointsEarned
```

**The endpoint accepts the list i.e PointList**

which shows me an error since the feeder accepts the feed-in FeedBuilder format. Now my question is how to convert the list to map.

I have gone through many examples but I couldn't get how to do it. Appreciate you help

Answer (score 1):

A gatling feeder is an Iterator that maps a String to Any.

So you can take your dataList and use .map and .toIterator to give you something you can call .feed on

```
val dataList = data.asScala.toList.map(point => Map("points" -> point).toIterator
```

So each time .feed is called, the next point value from your list will be put in the Session under the key "points". Note that you'll have to change your listed definition of Persist Points to use this value somewhere.

Depending on your needs, you might also be able to simplify your code by just defining a function that provides a random value on .feed

eg: if you just want a random point value between 0 and 100, you could redefine dataList to be...

```
val dataList = Iterator.continually(Map("points" -> Random.nextInt(101)))
```